# Issue in removing docker images remotely on CentOS

Tags: linux, bash, docker, kubernetes

I've installed a Kubernetes cluster using Rancher on 5 different CentOS nodes (let's say node1, node2, ..., node5). For our CI run, we need to clean up stale docker images before each run. I created a script that runs on node1, and password-less ssh is enabled from node1 to rest of the nodes. The relevant section of the script looks something like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
helm ls --short --all | xargs -L1 helm delete --purge

echo "Deleting old data and docker images from Rancher host node."
rm -rf /var/lib/hadoop/* /opt/ci/*
docker images | grep localhost | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f

hosts=(node2 node3 node4 node5)
for host in ${hosts[*]}
do
  echo "Deleting old data and docker images from ${host}"
  ssh root@${host} docker images | grep localhost | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f
  ssh root@${host} rm -rf /var/lib/hadoop/* /opt/ci/*
done
echo "All deletions are complete! Proceeding with installation."

sleep 2m
```

Problem is, while the `docker rmi` command inside the for loop runs for all other 4 nodes, I get the error `Error: No such image: <image-id>` for each of the images. But if I execute same command on that node, it succeeds. I'm not sure what's the issue here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add quotes to ssh command. The `docker images` is running on the remote machine but the rest the command beginning `grep localhost` is running on the local machine where you executed the script.

Comment: I think that might not be an issue. Actually I executed a partial command from node1 against node3, `ssh root@node3 docker images | grep localhost | awk '{print $3}'` and it listed down all image-ids present in node3

Comment: sure it prints images in node 3. Because `docker images` is executes at node 3. Then the output is transferred to node1 and grep and awk just filter the text data at node1. But when you try delete an image then you need to do it at node3. Try `ssh root@${host} "docker images | grep localhost | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f"`

Comment: @Zaboj Thanks a lot. That solved the issue.

Comment: As an aside, `awk '/localhost/ { print $3 }'` gets rid of the [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the only the first command in the ssh pipe is executed remotely:

```
ssh root@${host} docker images | grep localhost | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f
```

Shell understand that it is

```
ssh ssh-arguments | grep grep-arguments | awk awk-arguments | xarg xarg-arguments
```

And the result is that the only `docker images` is executed remotely. Then the output from the remote `docker images` is transferred to the local machine where it is filtered by `grep` and `awk` and then `docker rmi` is executed on local machine.

It is necessary to add quotes to inform shell that everything at command line is a ssh argument:

```
ssh root@${host} "docker images | grep localhost | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f"
```